# show only categories that have products in them

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, recursive-query

excuse the bad title but I couldn't find a good way to express what I want in abstract terms.

Anyway I have 3 tables

tbl_product:

```
PID | productname
1   | product 1
2   | product 2
3   | product 3
4   | product 4
..
```

tbl_categories, `motherCategory` allows me to nest categories:

```
CID | categoriename    | motherCategory
1   | electronics      | NULL
2   | clothing         | NULL
3   | Arduino          | 1
4   | Casings, extra's | 3
..
```

tbl_productInCategory PID and CID are foreign keys to PID and CID in tbl_product and tbl_categories respectively. A product can have multiple categories assigned to it so PID can occur more than once in this table.

```
PID | CID
1   | 1
2   | 1
3   | 3
4   | 4
```

Now I have a query that returns all categories if I give the mothercategory.
What I want to do is show ONLY the categories that have products in them recursively.

for instance on the example data above I show all categories(motherCategory is null), I want it to return only electronics since there are no products category 2, clothing.

However the problem I am having is that I also want this to work recursively. Consider this tbl_productInCategory:

```
PID | CID
1   | 2
2   | 2
3   | 2
4   | 4
```

Now it should return both clothing and electronics even though there are no products in electronics, because there are products in the nested category arduino->Casings, extra's. If I show all categories with motherCategory, electronics it should also return arduino.

I can't figure out how to do this and any help or pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should select all categories where products exist. On the next steps select mother categories.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT tbl_categories.*
FROM
tbl_categories
JOIN tbl_productInCategory on tbl_productInCategory.CID = tbl_categories.CID

UNION ALL 

SELECT tbl_categories.*
FROM tbl_categories 
JOIN CTE on tbl_categories.CID = CTE.motherCategory 
)
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive CTE to get a derived table of your category tree, and then INNER JOIN it to your ProductCategory table.

Comment: That appears to be a comment rather than an answer

Comment: Opinions vary, but the community at large would disagree:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318020/so-this-is-an-answer

Answer (score 0):

It's not something I've done before, but some googling indicates it is possible.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

> The semantics of the recursive execution is as follows:
>   Split the CTE expression into anchor and recursive members.
>   Run the anchor member(s) creating the first invocation or base result set (T0).
>   Run the recursive member(s) with Ti as an input and Ti+1 as an output.
>   Repeat step 3 until an empty set is returned.
>   Return the result set. This is a UNION ALL of T0 to Tn.

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
WITH DirectReports (ManagerID, EmployeeID, Title, DeptID, Level)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT e.ManagerID, e.EmployeeID, e.Title, edh.DepartmentID, 
        0 AS Level
    FROM dbo.MyEmployees AS e
    INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory AS edh
        ON e.EmployeeID = edh.BusinessEntityID AND edh.EndDate IS NULL
    WHERE ManagerID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
    SELECT e.ManagerID, e.EmployeeID, e.Title, edh.DepartmentID,
        Level + 1
    FROM dbo.MyEmployees AS e
    INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory AS edh
        ON e.EmployeeID = edh.BusinessEntityID AND edh.EndDate IS NULL
    INNER JOIN DirectReports AS d
        ON e.ManagerID = d.EmployeeID
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT ManagerID, EmployeeID, Title, DeptID, Level
FROM DirectReports
INNER JOIN HumanResources.Department AS dp
    ON DirectReports.DeptID = dp.DepartmentID
WHERE dp.GroupName = N'Sales and Marketing' OR Level = 0;
GO
```