# get all products that are in nested categories

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would really appreciate some help on this. my teacher couldn't help me.

Anyway I have 3 tables

tbl_product:

```
PID | productname
1   | product 1
2   | product 2
3   | product 3
4   | product 4
..
```

tbl_categories, motherCategory allows me to nest categories:

```
CID | categoriename    | motherCategory
1   | electronics      | NULL
2   | clothing         | NULL
3   | Arduino          | 1
4   | Casings, extra's | 3
..
```

tbl_productInCategory PID and CID are foreign keys to PID and CID in tbl_product and tbl_categories respectively. A product can have multiple categories assigned to it so PID can occur more than once in this table.

```
PID | CID
1   | 3
2   | 3
3   | 4
4   | 4
```

I want to select all products that are in a given category + it's subcategories. For instance if I give it the parameter CID = 1 (Electronics) it should also return the products in arduino and Casings, extra's.

I can't figure out how to do this and any help or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: You need to use a Recursive Common Table Expression.

Comment: You really should be able to solve this from the answer to this question:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682384/show-only-categories-that-have-products-in-them

Answer (score 0):

something like a recursive WITH

```
with recur AS 
    (
    SELECT CID,motherCategory FROM tbl_categories WHERE CID = @YourId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r2.CID, r2.motherCategory FROM tbl_categoriesr2 WHERE r2.motherCategory = recur.CID
    )

    SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE PID IN (SELECT CID FROM recur)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Common Table Expression like this:

```
declare @tbl_product table (
    PID int,
    productname nvarchar(50)
)

insert into @tbl_product(PID, productname)
select 1, 'product 1'
union
select 2, 'product 2'
union
select 3, 'product 3'
union
select 4, 'product 4'
union
select 5, 'product 5'


declare @tbl_categories table (
    CID int,
    categoriename nvarchar(50),
    motherCategory int
)

insert into @tbl_categories(CID, categoriename, motherCategory)
select 1,'electronics', NULL
union
select 2, 'clothing', NULL
union
select 3,  'Arduino', 1
union
select 4, 'Casings, extra''s', 3

declare @tbl_productInCategory table (
    PID int, 
    CID int
)

insert into @tbl_productInCategory(PID, CID)
select 1, 3
union
select 2, 3
union
select 3, 4
union
select 4, 4

-- COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION
;with category_cte (CID, categoriname, motherCategory)
AS
(   
    select CID, categoriename, motherCategory 
    from @tbl_categories 
    where CID = 1 -- THE CID YOU WANT TO USE
    UNION ALL
    select c.CID, c.categoriename, c.motherCategory 
    from @tbl_categories c
    inner join category_cte cte on c.motherCategory = cte.CID
)
select p.*
from @tbl_product p
inner join @tbl_productInCategory pic on p.PID = pic.PID
```

Note that there is a comment in the SQL where the CID is being used.